# How to build a custom dropdown menu in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a custom dropdown menu with Bootstrap 3.
Basically, the custom menu displays a full-width div with some components inside, instead of the usual ul>li Bootstrap menu.

There seems to be some kind of bug with Chrome (doesn't happen with Opera, Firefox, Safari).

Here's an example: http://bootply.com/89832

Clicking on 'categories' shows the custom menu correctly.
Clicking again hides it.
Clicking again shows it.
Clicking again does not hide it anymore.

I'm probably doing something wrong and Chrome has no bugs, but I really can't find it.
Also, is that the correct way to build a custom menu for non extra-small devices?
Please notice the classes I added to build 2 different menus.

Comment: It seems that the rpoblem is not in your code but in Chrome which is not updating the DOM. Play your own bootply demo and select 'Clothing' with the mouse when it should be hidden. It automatically disappears and your dropdown menu works again.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that. It disappears by going to the inspector, too. Any suggestions/critics about the HTML/CSS used to create the custom menu?

Comment: Not at all. The code is well built if you want to use a <div> instead <ul><li> cause it fits better to your requirements

Comment: use a dropdown with one option and CSS it. then disable the click to hide feature. i'm using this method too